# using pip to install dependencies from dependencies

Tags: python-3.x, tox

I would like to run some tests using tox, but in order for that to work he tries to import some modules first and he does that using pip.

My project is structured as described:

```
module_a/
 /tests/test_a.py
 /__requirements.txt
 /__tox.ini

module_b/
 /tests/test_b.py
 /__requirements.txt
 /__tox.ini

module_c/
 /tests/test_c.py
 /__requirements.txt
 /__tox.ini
```

```
module_a/requirements.txt

#requirements.txt content from module A
'../module_b'

module_b/requirements.txt
#requirements.txt content from module B
'../module_c'
```

What i expected was to import module_c just by requiring module_b because he requires him, but for some reason i cant, it throws the error

*ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement module_c (from module_b) (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for module_c*

So for that i had to also add module_c in module_a requirements.txt in order to work.

```
#requirements.txt content from module A
'../module_c'
'../module_b'
```

tox.ini file

```
[tox]
envlist =
    py3

[testenv]
deps =
    -r requirements.txt
commands =
    #basically the same for all modules, only module name changes
    pytest --cov {envsitepackagesdir}/module_a
```

Works fine if i just run pip install inside module_b, isn't like module_c has the wrong path.

There is a way to install dependencies from dependencies using a requirements.txt while running tox or just pip?

Comment: Can you please share your current `tox.ini`? And please add the output of `tree -L2` or similar. Thank you!

Comment: I put the tox.ini, but sorry to ask, what do you mean by tree -L2?

Comment: Thank you! `tree -L2` is linux command to show the directory structure 2 levels deep, but I just saw, you included some structure above. So, basically you have a folder, in which there are three subfolders (module_a, module_b, module_c), and each module has its own `tox.ini` and `requirements.txt`? Right? And running each project's tests via tox works, but now you like to run some integration tests between modules, and there you have a problem, right?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what is happening

Comment: I tried to do the same only using pip3 without tox, since tox uses pip3 for that and i had the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Given the latest feedback in the comments, this is not a `tox` issue, but rather an issue with structuring your project.

Usually, there are two ways to develop code together:

- put everything in one repository, and create a proper package (`__init__.py`) and then you can import the other sub-packages without a problem
- use different projects and repositories, and properly install the dependencies

There are some ways to change the second way, so you do can use the source code of other packages as dependencies.

I only know of one project doing this: morepath

You can have a look at their `tox.ini` configuration:

```
[src]
deps = -e file:{toxinidir}/src/reg#egg=reg
       -e file:{toxinidir}/src/dectate#egg=dectate
       -e file:{toxinidir}/src/importscan#egg=importscan

[testenv]
usedevelop = True
extras = test
deps = {[src]deps}
       -r{toxinidir}/requirements/fixtures.txt
```

You can find the complete configuration at...

https://github.com/morepath/morepath/blob/09972904229f807da75c75d8825af1495057acdc/tox.ini